# Meaning of these dialect words and phrases from Artemus Ward, "On Forts"

Tags: meaning, artemus-ward

I'm not a native English speaker and cannot get the full meaning of this part of Artemus Ward's work named "On Forts". I have highlighted difficult words:

> It is rarely seldum that I seek consolation in the **Flowin Bole**. But in a certain town in **Injianny** in the Faul of 18—, my **orgin grinder** got sick with the fever & died. I never felt so ashamed in my life, & I thowt I’d hist in a few swallers of suthin strengthnin. Konsequents was I **histid** in so much I dident zackly know whare bowts I was. I turned my livin wild beasts of Pray loose into the streets and spilt all my **wax wurks**. I then bet I cood play **hoss**. So I hitched myself to a Kanawl bote, there bein two other hosses **hicht** on also, one behind and anuther ahead of me. The driver hollerd for us to git up, and we did. But the hosses bein onused to sich a arrangemunt begun to kick & squeal and rair up. Konsequents was I was kickt vilently in the stummuck & back, and presuntly I fownd myself in the Kanawl with the other hosses, kickin & yellin like a tribe of Cusscaroorus savvijis. I was rescood, & as I was bein carrid to the tavern on a **hemlock Bored** I sed in a feeble voise, “Boys, playin hoss isn’t my Fort.”

I will be pleased if someone translates the difficult informal words into formal English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**'Flowin bole'**
Literally 'Flowing bowl', but figuratively 'alcohol', as in the traditional folksong  '[Come Landlord Fill the Flowing Bowl](http://wychwood.wikidot.com/songbook-come-landlord)'.

> Come landlord fill the flowing bowl
>   Until it doth run over.
>   Come landlord fill the flowing bowl
>   Until it doth run over.
>   For tonight we'll merry merry be
>   For tonight we'll merry merry be
>   For tonight we'll merry merry be
>   Tomorrow we'll be sober.

The meaning of the phrase 'seek consolation in the Flowin Bole' is therefore 'take comfort in alcohol'.

**'a certain town in Injianny'**
'Injianny' is the State of 'Indiana'. In '[Walden West' by August Derlleth](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fUF3DnydmggC&pg=PA198&lpg=PA198&dq=He%20had%20come%20to%20Sac%20Prairie%20from%20Indiana,%20and%20he%20never%20ceased%20to%20sing%20the%20praises%20of%20%22Injianny,%20where%20I%20come%20from&source=bl&ots=eJ8M7a27-M&sig=ACfU3U0BUgbbO4m4avXam-qwcqXg1QJK4Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1yvO9-fjmAhUkWhUIHZkiCFYQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=He%20had%20come%20to%20Sac%20Prairie%20from%20Indiana%2C%20and%20he%20never%20ceased%20to%20sing%20the%20praises%20of%20%22Injianny%2C%20where%20I%20come%20from&f=false) we read:

> He had come to Sac Prairie from Indiana, and he never ceased to sing the praises of "Injianny, where I come from."

**'my orgin grinder got sick with the fever & died'**
'Orgin grinder' is 'Organ Grinder', an operator of a ['barrel' or 'Street' organ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_organ). Per wikipedia:

> In many towns in Europe the barrel street organ was not just a solo performer, but used by a group of musicians as part of a story-telling street act, together with brightly coloured posters and sing-along sessions. In New York City, the massive influx of Italian immigrants led to a situation where, by 1880, nearly one in 20 Italian men in certain areas were organ grinders.

As a quote I include further down shows, the narrator's character runs a Traveling Show, so presumably the barrel organ and its grinder had a role in drumming up trade to the show.

**"Histid"**
I struggled a little with this one, but believe it to be an 'eye-dialect' spelling of 'hoisted', which [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/drunk) confirms as a synonym for 'drunk', which is the meaning suggested by the context.

**"Wax wurks"**
Simply "wax works", ie wax models of famous people which, in his drunkenness he damaged. I think 'spilt' here is eye-dialect for 'spoiled' rather than standard English 'spilt' meaning 'spilled'.
In the book [From Traveling Show to Vaudeville:Theatrical Spectacle in America, 1830–1910](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ijl-W-QoacMC&pg=PT21&lpg=PT21&dq=traveling%20show%20waxworks&source=bl&ots=1RaqvQouOh&sig=ACfU3U2oEMAizft84YVJ-TWpp3bymcTDfQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOiJad8_jmAhXSYcAKHeMoAIkQ6AEwDXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=traveling%20show%20waxworks&f=false) we read:

> Artemus Ward assumed the showman’s persona for his stage “lectures” and his humorous essays on “the show bizness” in Vanity Fair. “I’m travelin with a tent, which is better nor [than] hirin hauls,” Ward announced to his readers in 1857. “ my show konsists of a serious of waxworks, snakes and a paneramy kalled a Grand Movin Diarea of the War in the Crymear, komic songs and the Cangeroo.”

**Hoss**- Horse

**hicht**- Hitched

**hemlock Bored**
'Hemlock board' ie a plank of wood from the 'Tsuga' family of trees, most likely [Tsuga canadensis](https://www.wood-database.com/eastern-hemlock/), (Eastern Hemlock) or [Tsuga heterophylla](https://www.trada.co.uk/wood-species/hemlock-western/) (Western Hemlock).

Comment: Great answer! Nice and comprehensive.